# How to check well-formedness of 4GB XML file?

Tags: xml

I want to check well-formedness of a big XML file. (about 4GB.)

However, when I try `xmlwf`, all it tells me is

```
filename.xml: Value too large for defined data type
```

What to do with it? Is there any other way to check it?

(I am using debian linux and gentoo linux)

Comment: I'd guess any XML parser would work, as aren't they required to reject documents which aren't well-formed? A quick suggests checking if xmlstarlet does what you want.

Comment: From `man xmlwf`: "-r Normally xmlwf memory-maps the XML file before parsing; this can result  in  faster parsing on many platforms.  -r turns off memory-mapping and uses normal file IO calls instead. Of  course, memory-mapping  is  automatically  turned  off when reading from standard input." By the way, I assume you are using a 64-bit setup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to try [dtdgen](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/dtdgen.html), a program I wrote many years ago to generate a DTD for a document. It not only tells you whether a large file is well-formed, it also tells you what's in it (I wrote it because I wanted to know both).

Answer (score 2):

```
xmllint --noout 4GB.xml
```

That sort of works.

It goes out of memory, too, but at least it checks something before it dies.

Comment: does `xmlint` ship with most distros or do you have to install it separately?

Comment: @amphibient If not installed you have to install expat.

Answer (score 0):

Not try it myself, but try this out :

```
xmllint --valid 4GB.xml
```

Comment: I don't want to try if it's valid. I want to try if it's well-formed.

Comment: Can you spot me the difference ?

Comment: http://www.xmlblueprint.com/help/html/topic_118.htm

Comment: basically, it can't be valid if it doesn't have DTD. And I haven't yet wrote the DTD :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an older question, but as I haven't seen it suggested yet:

Perl with [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) can handle large XML files thanks to having a 'purge' method, which discards in memory data as you go.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        _all_ => sub { $_->purge }
    }
)->parsefile( 'my_xml_file.xml' );
```

The `_all_` handler is triggered each element of the twig, and discards in memory data. That's important on a 4G file, because the memory footprint of XML is about 10x. But it'll throw an alert and abort if the XML is not well formed:

```
mismatched tag at line 12, column 27, byte 274 at C:/Perl/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
```

(but bear in mind because it aborts, it'll only show you the *first* error it encounters).

Works on my (much smaller than 4G) sample data anyway.